# How to make REST API call using a token?

Tags: java, api, rest, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I am newbie developer in Java. STEP 1 I have already done the the following:

1. Logged in to REST API server (with login&password)
2. Received a token in XML format which i parsed with SAX parser so now i 
   am in a position of a token. Below is the sample code for Login:

Java code:

```
 String url1 = "https://api4.liverail.com/login";
 URL obj = new URL(url1);
 HttpsURLConnection con1 = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
 String urlParameters ="username=paania@gmail.com&password=d372a15b714bd250e";
 con1.setDoOutput(true);
 con1.setRequestMethod("POST");
 DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con1.getOutputStream());
 wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
```

STEP 2: I want to pass the token to REST API to obtain some information e.g a list from category but when i send the request via GET method , i get a response in XML saying `[CDATA[You need to be logged in]]` This is the code in Java:

```
String url =  "http://api4.liverail.com/advertising/category/list/?token="72938howdwoi";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
in.close();
con.disconnect();
```

I am not sure what i am missing here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just changed your `url` for request of data :

```
String url =  "http://api4.liverail.com/advertising/category/list/?token=72938howdwoi";
```

Comment: I did but it not keep on saying "you need to be logged in". I am not sure if i am doing the right think by sending the token via url?

Comment: Try removing `/` before `?`.